# Create a new variable as named from input in Python?

Tags: python, variables, initialization, runtime

This is something that I've been questioning for some time. How would I create a variable at runtime as named by the value of another variable. So, for example, the code would ask the user to input a string. A variable would then be created named after that string with a default value of "default". Is this even possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Whatever he's trying to achieve, this approach is wrong. Use a `dict` (or another suitable collection - but if you want to use a string, you propably want a `dict`), period.

Comment: Python internals are so transparent that it's tempting to say how to do this, but much more interesting would be coming up with a case where it's a good idea.

Comment: I'm not trying to achieve anything anymore. I figured I had to do it a while back, but the same can be achieved with dict. It's more now of a 'Is that even possible?' question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but it's certainly not advised. You can access the global namespace as a dict (it's a dict internally) and add entries to it.

If you were doing an interactive interpreter, say, for doing maths, or something. You would actually pass a dict to each eval() or exec that you could then re-use as it's local namespace.

As a quick, bad, example, don't do this at home:

```
g = globals() # get a reference to the globals dict
g[raw_input("Name Please")] = raw_input("Value Please")
print foo
```

Run that, it'll traceback unless you provide 'foo' to the first prompt.